# How to show a form infront of all windows interfaces (start screen)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, topmost

I want to make a WinForms with make it in Front of Many thing (in Windows 8, it in front of Start Screen, even make it can leave desktop while desktop Snapping).

for example, A Magnifier (magnify.exe) dialog in Windows 8 are top most than Start Screen.

It is Possible to make this Happen (In VB or C#)?

This Image is Example for what I ask for, so far I didn't find any SDK do this, and this image are edited (none of many application do this except magnifier (magnify.exe))

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UxCX.png

alternative :

https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B0xI21kQ3jxrLWw4cll6X3NJSTA&export=download

Comment: When your program runs twice - which instance should be on top? Your question is famous and futile.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the form modal by calling [`Form.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

Don't forget to set [`Form.DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) accordingly on your modal form.

An easy example could be like the following:

```
Form f = new Form();
f.ShowDialog(this);
```

The other option is to set the form's [`TopMost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx) property to true.

Finally, you have the [`Modal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.modal(v=vs.110).aspx) property which will block all other no modal forms from click or keyboard events.

But given that WinForms is a desktop app, you will be able to show it in the desktop of windows 8, but not the new Metro interface.

Comment: what i meaning it must be in front than everything, for example if i make fullscreen winforms then I hit Windows Key, then Start Screen/Menu will not appear, besause my Winforms are on top than Windows Start Screen/Menu